# Loading CloudFormation YAML using Python

Tags: python, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I've got a set of `YAML`  AWS Cloud Formation Templates that I've recently converted from `JSON`.

When using `JSON` I was able to load these templates and transform them using `jinja` to generate some markdown documentation from them. I'm attempting to do the same with `YAML` in python.

I'm using the shorthand function syntax in the cloudformation templates which uses the `YAML` Tags. eg

```
Properties:
  MinSize: !Ref ClusterSize
  MaxSize: !Ref ClusterSize
```

When attempting to load these with the `ruamel.yaml` package the Constructor fails because it is unable to handle the Tags, because it has no knowledge about them.

Is there a way I can work around this so that I'm able to load the `YAML` document so that I can retrieve/query the Outputs and Resources?

Comment: What are the "Outputs" and "Resources"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mistaken that `ruamel.yaml` cannot handle tags. But of course you have to provide the information on how to handle any unknown tags, it cannot guess what kind of data you want to load with `!Ref`:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
Properties:
  MinSize: !Ref ClusterSize
  MaxSize: !Ref ClusterSize
"""


class Blob(object):
    def update(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)


def my_constructor(self, node):
    data = Blob()
    yield data
    value = self.construct_scalar(node)
    data.update(value)

ruamel.yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor(u'!Ref', my_constructor)

data = ruamel.yaml.safe_load(yaml_str)
print('data', data['Properties']['MinSize'])
```

prints:

```
ClusterSize
```

If you want to get rid of many different tags, and don't care about "everything being a string" you can also do:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
Properties:
  MinSize: !Ref ClusterSize
  MaxSize: !Ref ClusterSize
  SizeList:
     - !abc 1
     - !xyz 3
"""


def general_constructor(loader, tag_suffix, node):
    return node.value


ruamel.yaml.SafeLoader.add_multi_constructor(u'!', general_constructor)


data = ruamel.yaml.safe_load(yaml_str)
print(data)
```

which gives:

```
{'Properties': {'SizeList': ['1', '3'], 'MinSize': 'ClusterSize', 'MaxSize': 'ClusterSize'}}
```

(Please note that the scalars `1` and `3` are loaded as string instead of the normal integer)

Comment: Thanks Anthon, I didn't mean to imply that ruamel.yaml could not handle tags - I just don't know the behaviour and implementation of those tags and because I don't know how to specify them I can't load the YAML.

Their are more tags then just !Ref, and some are accept lists and other other Types - Is there a way I can ignore tags, or treat them as strings, or does this not work on a more fundamental level?

Comment: If everything can be a string then that is relatively simple, it is a bit unfortunate that you had reduced your sample YAML so far that it looked like you had only one such tag and only nested dictionaries. I'll update the answer.