# How to serialize escaped strings in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, serialization, pyyaml

I'm trying to a .yml policy document for AWS. The problem is my list of strings is being surrounded in double quotes "" when I try to escape it myself, i.e. 
- "'acm:AddTagsToCertificate'".

When I do nothing, it shows as 
- acm:AddTagsToCertificate.

Problem is I need the final result in the .yml to look like 
- 'acm:AddTagsToCertificate'

In terms of my own trouble shooting, I've tried using double and single quotations. I've also tried subclassing list to override how lists are serialized until other SO answers said that was frowned upon.

Here's the reduced code which shows my issue

```
import yaml;

data = {'apigateway:CreateDeployment': 6}

actions = [];

for key in data:
  key = "\'" + key + "\'"
  print(key)
  actions.append(key);

with open('test.yml', 'w') as output:
  yaml.dump(actions, output, default_flow_style=False)
```

Comment: Not your issue but Python doesn't need `;`. It is just used to do statements on a single line.

Comment: Yeah that just comes from consistency in my code with languages which do require semicolons. Personal habit

Comment: Are you sure you really need `'` over `"`? Does the targetsystem complain? string in yaml need neither ... if they do not contain special things or look like numbers/dates... wich yours do not.,

Comment: @PatrickArtner Did not know that.  I was going off templates my work has already, matching their formatting. I'll try to validate without the quotes and see what happens.

Comment: One thing I notice upon reading your comment is the problem with the first result is that it has both a double and single quote. I need one or the other, not both. Single is preferred though as that's the current style used at work. I did try it without any quotations and the results are working so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `default_style="'"` in the `dump`:

```
import yaml

data = {'apigateway:CreateDeployment': 6}

actions = list(data.keys())

with open('test.yml', 'w') as output:
  yaml.dump(actions, output, default_flow_style=False, default_style="'")
```

Comment: That does get me closer to the format I'm looking for and does solve the issue with the quotations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it solves this issue :)

Comment: What's interesting is that it solves the trivial example but introduces issues with formatting the actual human readable cloudformation template. Do you have insight into what exactly is going on here within the library to cause the issue? I think I'm just not understanding how the library is doing its formatting. I've tried looking at the documentation before and find it wanting.

Comment: Cloud formation isn't valid YAML exactly (at least not if it requires this type of formatting). The `yaml` module is designed for YAML and works perfect for that but if you are trying to conform to cloud formation template semantics then you will need the jury rig some stuff.

Comment: That being said are you sure you need the single quote marks? [This question doesn't use them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41090021/8150685).